# Most Efficient Way to Add Millisecond Timestamps to MongoDB with C++ Driver

Tags: c++, mongodb, timestamp

I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to create documents with millisecond level timestamps. After some fooling around my current approach is as follows:

My timestamps are originally in boost::posix_time::ptime format. I can create a ptime object from a millisecond level timestamp string using the boost::posix_time::time_from_string function:

```
std::string ts("2012-01-20 15:47:59.223");
ptime pt (time_from_string(ts));
```

I can then convert the ptime object to a mongo:DateT object:

```
mongo::Date_t  dt = convert(pt);
```

where convert is defined as:

```
mongo::Date_t convert(const boost::posix_time::ptime& pt)
{
    boost::posix_time::ptime epoch(boost::gregorian::date(1970,boost::date_time::Jan,1));
    boost::posix_time::time_duration d = pt - epoch;
    return mongo::Date_t(d.total_milliseconds());
}
```

I then append the Date_t object to an instance of mongo::BSONObjBuilder:

```
mongo::BSONObjBuilder builder;
builder.genOID();
builder.appendDate ("datetime", dt );
```

And finally, create a BSONObj and insert to the database.

```
BSONObj doc = builder.obj();

mongo.insert(collection, doc);
```

In this the most efficient approach? I need to be able to search the database at millisecond level. I also need to be able to query on date and time separately. Do I need to add two additional fields, so that there are three time related fields: datetime, date, and time?......... and then create indexes for each of these fields? Is there a better approach?

Thanks,

Rob.

Comment: You can just keep the millisecond approach and then when searching for dates or times just use some mathemagic to change a date to a millisecond interval or a given time to the same.

Comment: I have decided on the following approach. I include three time related fields.

Comment: Its possible to use $dayOfMonth and similar routines for aggregations on a single millisecond field -- but not for non-aggregated/standard finds. thus separate (day, month, milliseconds) are needed for these use cases (to my knowledge). i have tried using $mod routines but those donut work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the MongoDB Date type. This stores the date in a more efficient format than a string and includes millisecond accuracy. You can then have a single index on the field which you can query using any date/time.

I'd also recommend reading http://blog.pythonisito.com/2012/09/mongodb-schema-design-at-scale.html which has some recommendations for storing time series data in MongoDB, especially if you're doing a lot of updates.